# Removing the last character from an NSMutableString

Tags: objective-c

How does one remove the last character from an NSMutableString?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You could use [deleteCharactersInRange:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000156-deleteCharactersInRange_)

```
NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"FooBarx"];
[str deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([str length]-1, 1)];
```