# How to fix warning: Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableString *' from 'NSString *'

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablestring

I have this line of code that is giving me a warning:

```
result = [result substringToIndex:[result length] - 1];
```

The warning is:

> Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableString *' from 'NSString *'

I think I understand what the problem is (my use of the substring returns NSString?) - I just don't know how to fix it.  Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: This is the same problem as your earlier [Incompatible pointer types initializing NSMutableArray with an expression of](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19101395)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675609/removing-the-last-character-from-an-nsmutablestring):

```
[result deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([result length]-1, 1)];
```

Thanks for the effort; I appreciate it.  SD

Answer (score 17):

```
result = [[result substringToIndex:[result length] - 1] mutableCopy]
```

Assuming result is of class NSMutableString.